# Clarification of Python code snippet? (Printing only some of a list at a time)

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop

I was given this piece of code by my printer for long lists so Python would only display x(in this case 9) items in the list before prompting the user to press enter. I've gotten it to work for some of my lists, but for the rest it'll print at uneven amounts and sometimes not any items at all. She never explained it, she just gave it to us so I all I need is clarification on what this does so I can effectively apply it to other lists. All I've done so far is change the_list to the one I was using and then put print (the_list) or whatever I needed printed.

```
for ind in range (0,len(the_list)):
     if ind%10==9:
         input("Press ENTER to continue")
     print("information")
```

Also, even if this might not be the most effective way of doing this, it's the way she gave me so I assume it's what she wants us to use. For future reference, I don't mind if you give me a different code altogether but I need to know how to apply this one for this certain project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably expected. It isn't printing 9 *lines*, it's printing 9 *items*. Each item could be an empty string (which won't print anything), to a few words, to whole screens of text.

example:

```
list1 = [chr(a+65) for a in range(26)]
list2 = [chr(a+65)*300 for a in range(26)]

In [287]: list1[0]
'a'

In [288]: list2[0]
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

The first one just creates an array of the characters from A to Z.
The second one, creates a long list (300 characters) for each letter. 
Since your console is probably 80 characters, printing just one line of this will wrap your screen 3 times. So printing list2 will take 4 times the number of screen lines vs. list1.

There's nothing wrong with your code, but the better way would be to print your representation into a string, split it by line, and then show some number of screen lines at a time, instead of items. Not quite the same thing, but IPython's %page magic does something very similar; it prints a representation of your object, but lets you page through it.

Comment: Okay, I understand now! I actually gave it parameters so Python would only print certain items out of my list. I told it to print 9 at a time but not all 9 would fit the parameters so it'd skip some. Thank you so much for your help!